# Meson: How to generate "header-only" dependency

Tags: dependencies, meson-build

I have an executable that relies on an IPC as an external interface.
I compile this exec using the meson build system.
The external header is properly exported.

I'm trying to register this with pkgconfig, but the pkgconfig module needs a library to link against.
Here I just need to declare the exported header file, I need a header-only declaration.

Here is an extract of the meson.build file:

```
executable('myexec',
    src,
    include_directories : inc,
    dependencies : deps,
    install : true)

myexec = library('myexec')
pkgconfig = import('pkgconfig')
pkgconfig.generate(myexec)
    version : '1.0',
    subdirs : 'myexec')

install_headers('include/myexec.h',
    subdir : 'myexec')
```

With this, everything goes well except that the generated .pc files contains a non-empty Libs field and the clients relying on myexec.h don't have a library to link against:

```
prefix=/usr/local
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: myexec
Description: buttond: myexec
Version: 1.0
Libs: -L${libdir} -lmyexec       # here is my issue!
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Linking the client executable that make calls from myexec.h

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmyexec
```

Is this the proper way to generate such package?
Am I missing an option to pkgconfig module to force the correct .pc generation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by *pkgconfig module needs a library to link against*.
But no **library()** needed in case of header-only package. This should work:

```
pkgconfig = import('pkgconfig')
pkgconfig.generate(
    name : 'myexec',
    version : '1.0',
    subdirs : ['.', 'myexec'])
```

(here I assume the headers will be installed to ${PREFIX}/include/myexec dir)

It looks also that you are missing propagation of myexec dependencies into generated .pc file - but that's another question.

Comment: This works well, the first argument to pkgconfig.generate() is optional.
But I was missing the "name" argument.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the dependencies propagation. That's indeed something I overlooked.

Comment: @adrien I mean in case your header-library also depends on some other library - just check if they are propagated to Requires: field or Clfags: (additional include directories) added as result of declare_dependency(...)